# Are the derivatives in Sobolev norms supposed to exist in the WEAK sense?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was wondering whether or not the derivatives in Sobolev norms exist in the **weak** sense. Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $1\leq p<\infty$. In the PDE book by Lawrence C. Evans, among many lecture notes on the internet, the **Sobolev space** $W^{k,p}(U)$ is defined to be the space of all locally summable functions $u:U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for each multi-index $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|\leq k$, $D^\alpha u$ exists in the weak sense and belongs to $L^p(U)$. This common definition is clear to me and bears no ambiguity, but when it comes to the norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{W^{k,p\ \ }(U)}$ defined by
$$\lVert u\rVert_{W^{k,p\ \ }(U)}=\left(\sum_{|\alpha\leq k|}\int_U|D^\alpha u|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p},\tag{$*$}$$
somehow I don't feel so confident to conclude that the derivatives $D^\alpha u$ inside the integral are understood in the weak sense. Evans and many lecture notes didn't talk about it, and I wonder why. Does the $L^p$ norm involved in $(*)$ implicitly show consideration for weak derivatives? Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain further your concern? We have $D^{\alpha}u\in L^p(U)$ so we can take the integral and it is finite.

Comment: Yes, $D^\alpha$ here means weak derivative.  What else could it be?  If it was required to be a classical derivative, then we certainly wouldn't get the usual Sobolev space (in particular it would not be a Banach space).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, guys. I just didn't feel right to use weak derivatives, and as an average self-learner, I frequently hesitate to draw a conclusion on my own.